# Overvoltage protection for low side MOSFET using TVS or Zener

Tags: mosfet, over-voltage-protection

For the following overvoltage scheme taken from [this](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-ApplicationNote_v12-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4625b62cd8a015bc8c8e5ae31d1) document, it appears that a zener diode is used to turn the gate of the MOSFET on when the drain voltage exceeds a certain value. For this protection scheme, does it make a difference if a zener diode or transient voltage suppression diode is used?

Note: There is a pulldown resistor between the gate and source.

[image]

Comment: It depends on what connects to the gate connection going left but unshown.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie a TVS diode doesn't short i.e. it behaves very similarly to a zener and clamps to a specific voltage for a specific surge current.